# How does Spring JPA derive queries?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am wondering how does Spring JPA derive queries from methods. As an example, if I was to type
`interface CarRepo extends CrudRepository<Car, Long>{ findByCarMake(Make make) }`
my query would be automatically derived from the method and would be something as "SELECT * from Car WHERE carMake = xxxxx"
I do understand this concepts but I would like to understand how it works behind the scenes. So, how does it actually derive a query from the method name?
I am aiming at creating a similar thing to suit our needs for a NestJs project so in Typescript not Java and also for an..."unorthodox" database which does not have such support out of the box( Neo4J).

I ll be very grateful to whom can and will help me.

Comment: The project is open-source, you can inspect its sources to see how it achieves this.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA derives the queries from the method names in your repository.

There are [certain keywords that are reserved by Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords). One the one hand, there are query subject keywords like `findBy`, `existsBy`, `countBy`, etc. which influence the return type of the method. On the other hand, there are operators like `and`, `or`, `isIn`, `between`, etc. that are applied to the actual query logic.

You start your query with a query subject keyword like `findBy` and then the fields of your entity (and optionally operators and more fields). You can even have nested fields like `findByProviderName` where your entity has a field `provider` which has a field `name`. If you define an invalid property or property path (e.g. `findByProviderNamw`), your Spring Boot application would fail on startup. You can find more about defining query methods in [the official spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

Comment: Spring doesn't support dervied queries for actions like "create" does it?

Answer (score -2):

Spring Data using `part tree JPA queries`, than map them into SQL query by pre-defined parts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).